# PHP calculate hours

Tags: php

I have two variables, example:

```
$from = 13:43:13;

$to = 18:53:13;
```

I need to calculate in PHP the hours between `$from` and `$to`, so that `$total` will be like:

```
$total = 5.10 // 5 hours and ten minutes
```

or

```
$total = 0.40 // 0 hours and 40 minutes
```

I do not mind seconds, what I need is hours and minutes.

Please help me :)

Comment: `0.40` hours would be 24 minutes, not 40.

Answer (score 5):

```
$from       = '13:43:13';
$to         = '18:53:13';

$total      = strtotime($to) - strtotime($from);
$hours      = floor($total / 60 / 60);
$minutes    = round(($total - ($hours * 60 * 60)) / 60);

echo $hours.'.'.$minutes;
```

Comment: 09:19 - 09:12 = 0.07. NOT 0.7 which the above code would give. 09:49 - 09:34 = 0.15 (correct). So in turn, adding 0.7+0.15 = 0.85 (incorrect). Should be 0.07+0.15 = 0.22 (correct). Finding this issue with every example I come across.

Comment: The idea here was the number before the decimal point should be the number of hours and the number after it should be the number of minutes. Since there are 0 hours and 7 minutes between your times it should return 0.7, not 0.07. It's not a particularly useful figure in my opinion, but it's what the OP wanted...

Answer (score 4):

I like using the object-oriented approach, using the [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class:

```
$from = new DateTime('13:43:13');
$to = new DateTime('18:53:13');

echo $from->diff($to)->format('%h.%i'); // 5.10
```

Answer (score 0):

How about making about a function and putting the below code into that?

```
<?php
    $from = $_REQUEST['start_time']; 
    $to = $_REQUEST['end_time']; 
    $action = $_REQUEST['action']; 
?> 

<? 
    if($action && ($action == "go")){ 
        list($hours, $minutes) = split(':', $from); 
        $startTimestamp = mktime($hours, $minutes); 

        list($hours, $minutes) = split(':', $to); 
        $endTimestamp = mktime($hours, $minutes); 

        $seconds = $endTimestamp - $startTimestamp; 
        $minutes = ($seconds / 60) % 60; 
        $hours = round($seconds / (60 * 60)); 

        echo "Time passed: <b>$hours</b> hours and <b>$minutes</b> minutes"; 
    } 
?>
```

Please add the fields to receive the values...

Answer (score 0):

There's a flaw in the calculation. The result shows 5.2 when it should be 5.02.
Try using 09:58 as the start time and 15:00 as the end time.